# Student’s T-test

Tags: regression, t-test, matlab, dataset

I am currently doing research using Matlab where I am looking at a variable in convective weather (i.e. 200 values of CO2 content) and comparing it to the same variable with a different length in non-convective weather (i.e. 100 values of C02 content.)

I wanted to first verify this would be a paired t-test (as opposed to unpaired) before getting further into my research. And secondly, using Matlab does anyone have a suggestion on what to run for two data sets of different lengths? I was going to try:

[H,PValue]=ttest(Sample1,Sample2)

Also, is a “student’s t-test” different from just a regular “t-test?” Someone suggested that I run the students t-test but from what I have read that is for unpaired data while I am thinking that my data is paired.

Thank you!

Comment: In what sense would any of the 200 values be paired with a particular value from the 100 non-convective values?

Comment: This is where I am drawing some confusion. I was thinking that since they are the same variable in different conditions they would be paired and that I would use an unpaired test if I were looking at, say two different variables

Comment: It would help to expand on what these variables represent, because it appears you may be aware of some as yet unstated connections among them that would be important for any valid test to recognize.

Comment: I am testing multiple variables such as nitrate content, sulfate content, black carbon content, etc. that are found in the atmosphere. For each variable, I want to compare its presence in non-convective air against convective air and am attempting to see if there is a statistically significant difference between the two. So in short, I do not know of any connection between the two besides just their presence in the atmosphere. Hopefully this gives you a better idea of what I am trying to do and thank you for the help.